# How do I set order by sum of values in join tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, controller, sum

I am trying to create a leader table in my view. I am displaying a list of all Users, each user can enter 1 or more events (user has and belongs to many events through => results) in each result is the :points won in the relative event.

I am having trouble writing the controller. I want something to the effect of

```
@standings = User.find(:all, :order => 'User.results.points.sum');
```

So a list of all users in order of the sum of point in each of their results.

(I know the code above is a long way off - it is just my attempt to illustrate what i'm after )

Would be very grateful if someone could give me some advice on the best way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following:

```
User.joins(:results).group("users.id").order("SUM(results.points)")
```

Joins users to the results table, groups by user, then orders by the sum of results.points.

Then you can adjust ordering like so if you want highest number of points first:

```
User.joins(:results).group("users.id").order("SUM(results.points) DESC")
```